# Disable Mi5 Touchscreen Input via adb

Tags: adb, touchscreen, xiaomi

I've got a Xiaomi Mi5 (gemini) and I encounter the problem of ghost input. I guess my phone could be water-damaged even though I'm not sure. To backup my data I need to access the phone (not just it's flash memory, I need to backup using specific apps). The phone itself still works fine, except the abnormal touchscreen which is ghost touching the phone permanently. I need to disable specific parts of the touchscreen, or if not possible the touchscreen drivers themselves.

I've already tried [this solution](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/119334/disable-touchscreen-input-via-console), but my init.rc does not include any /tsp.

Comment: What I've successfully tried so far:
1. rm -rf /dev/input/event2 (disables touchscreen input)
2. touch /dev/input/event2 (enables adb input tap /swipe funcitonality)
3. pm install teamviewer.apk (downloaded from net) and adb shell monkey -p app.package.name -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER 1 (replaced app.package.name by TeamViewer package name)
4. Etablished connection
BUT... I can't touch input my device :/
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I've found the solution myself.

To follow the steps check these requirements:

- superuser permissions
- debugging enabled
- ability to accept debugging request on phone

Find and delete the file which proceeds touch input. In my case it was `/dev/input/event2`, but it can be another file in the `dev/input` directory as well. To delete execue the following commands (given adb-tools are installed):

1. `adb shell`
2. `su` (grant superuser permissions)
3. `rm -rf /dev/input/event2` (replace `event2` with your corresponding file if necessary)
4. `touch /dev/input/event2` (to be able to use input commands such as `input tap x y` and `input swipe x y x y`, replace event2 with corresponding file if necessary)